# Spring data order search correctly

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

In my Repository i create the folowing method:

```
List<customer> findTop5ByNameContains(String name);
```

imagining that I have these customers:

```
[{name: 'spongebob', id: 1}, {name: 'Bob dylan', id: 2}]
```

, when i search 'bob', the result comes:
spongebob, Bob Dylan.
How to sort first the records that start with the parameter and then the records that contain the parameter?

Comment: Did my answer help you? Please, mark as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should recommend you to use  and "Exemple Matcher" 

i.e.:

```
public List<Customer> search(Customer customer) {
  ExampleMatcher matcher = ExampleMatcher
            .matching()
            .withIgnoreCase()
            .withIgnoreNullValues()
            .withStringMatcher(ExampleMatcher.StringMatcher.CONTAINING)
            .withMatcher("name", startsWith())
            .withIgnorePaths("id");
  Example<Customer> query = Example.of(customer, matcher);

  return repository.findAll(query);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According with the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation), you should use "Starting with". Try this:

```
 List<customer> findTop5ByNameStartingWith(String name);
```